# How to handle exceptions and why they might be ignored at times

Tags: c#, exception, visual-studio-2013, nullreferenceexception, kinect-sdk

The important bits of my code look like this:

```
sensor.ColorFrameReady += sensor_ColorFrameReady;

void sensor_ColorFrameReady(object sender, ColorImageFrameReadyEventArgs colorImageFrameReadyEventArgs)
    {
        using (var frame = colorImageFrameReadyEventArgs.OpenColorImageFrame())
        {
            var bitmap = CreateBitmap(frame);
            Canvas.Background = new ImageBrush(bitmap);
        }
    }

private static BitmapSource CreateBitmap(ColorImageFrame frame)
    {
        var pixelData = new byte[frame.PixelDataLength];
        frame.CopyPixelDataTo(pixelData);
        var stride = frame.Width * frame.BytesPerPixel;
        var bitmap = BitmapSource.Create(frame.Width, frame.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null, pixelData, stride);
        return bitmap;
    }

private void PictureButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        using(var frame = sensor.ColorStream.OpenNextFrame(0))
        {
            var bitmap = CreateBitmap(frame);
            Canvas.Background = new ImageBrush(bitmap);
        }
    }
```

Whenever I run my application, I get the error: "An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred". This happens at the first line of my BitMapSource method.

I fixed this by adding the following if statement to my BitmapSource method:

```
private static BitmapSource CreateBitmap(ColorImageFrame frame)
    {
      if(frame != null)
      {
         var pixelData = new byte[frame.PixelDataLength];
         frame.CopyPixelDataTo(pixelData);
         var stride = frame.Width * frame.BytesPerPixel;
         var bitmap = BitmapSource.Create(frame.Width, frame.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null, pixelData, stride);
         return bitmap;    
      }
      else {throw new Exception();}
    }
```

1. I wanted to check if this is the correct way to handle this particular exception? I noticed some sources do exactly this. However, some say never ever to use `throw new Exception`. Is this correct?
2. Also, in the tutorial I am following, the person runs the above code without coming across an exception like I do (thus not needing the if statement I added). Does anyone know why this is? Do previous versions of VS ignore this type of exception or is something else going on here?

Comment: Find out why the exception is happening. You probably have a bug somewhere. You should always try to prevent exceptions from happening and only use them if the circumstances are truly exceptional.

Comment: My code is identical to the one in the tutorial, so I can't think why. I figured rather than a bug, this was simply happening because I had to explicitly make sure I'm not passing any null's, though that doesn't explain why the person in the tutorial was able to run his code without his version of VS picking up a exception.

Comment: It's always possible the tutorial is buggy. But at the same time I think you should figure out why you are getting a null rather than try to handle it after the fact. My guess is that `OpenNextFrame` eventually reaches the end of the frames in the stream... so you should make sure it only tries to create a bitmap if there are any frames left.

Comment: From the docs for [`ColorImageFrameReadyEventArgs.OpenColorImageFrame()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.colorimageframereadyeventargs.opencolorimageframe.aspx): "A frame of color data in a new ColorImageFrame object, or NULL if the data is no longer available."  So, you need to find out why the data is no longer available.

Comment: Since the docs say that `OpenColorImageFrame` can return null, you should maybe just not even _call_ `CreateBitmap` if you get a null back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. To answer your first question, the `if (frame != null)` part is a fine way to verify that the argument is not null. In the `else` clause, however, it would be better to throw a more meaningful exception, something like:

   `else { throw new ArgumentNullException("frame"); }`
2. To answer your second question: No, previous versions of Visual Studio did not ignore `NullReference` exceptions. It's likely that the tutorial left out some error handling for simplicity/readability (or laziness). It would be a good idea to look at the code that's calling this method and try to figure out why it's passing a null `frame`.

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.colorimageframereadyeventargs.opencolorimageframe.aspx) documentation, it could be passing null in the `sensor_ColorFrameReady` method if the data is no longer available.

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.colorimagestream.opennextframe.aspx) documentation, it should not be returning null in your `PictureButton_Click` method, since you're passing in `0` for milisecondsWait.

Comment: Interestingly, I noticed that sometimes (quite rarely) everything works perfectly and there is no error. I've been trying the last 2 hours but can't find whats causing these damn null's :(